# Problem with Maven and a HelloWorld.java project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have this in my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>training.maven.quick</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimal-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</project>
<properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

I use Git Bash and when I use:

```
mvn package
```

The problem is the following:

```
$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\clmonreal\MavensProject\minimal\pom.xml: sta tag not allowed in epilog but got p (position: END_TAG seen ...</version>\n</pject>\n<p... @10:3)  @ line 10, column 3
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project  (C:\Users\clmonreal\MavensProject\minimal\pom.xml) has 1rror
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM C:\Users\clmonreal\MavensProject\minimal\pom.xml:tart tag not allowed in epilog but got p (position: END_TAG seen ...</version>\/project>\n<p... @10:3)  @ line 10, column 3 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swih.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please re the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildiException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseExction
```

Comment: Please post code and error messages as texts, not images. Please see: [ask]

Comment: Your POM is not well-formed. An XML document cannot have multiple root tags and the properties element must be a child element of the project

Comment: I am using the example of this link: https://github.com/srctips/maven-course-content/blob/master/minimal/pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All tags in maven should be between `<project>` and `</project>`

## Instead of:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>training.maven.quick</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimal-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</project>
<properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

## Do:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>training.maven.quick</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimal-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

   <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
</project>
```

this is because if bar is inside foo it would be:

```xml
<foo>
   <bar>
   </bar>
</foo> <!-- close of foo -->
```

for more info look up xml syntax

Hope this helps